# Pandas Dataframe: AttributeError

Tags: python, pandas

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

I receive this Error, while trying to work on a certain column in my dataframe. I read in an excel file with the pandas function `pd.read_excel`.

```
change_copy.NAMECHANGE = change_copy.NAMECHANGE.str.replace("_Ja","_Nein")
```

This is the line where the error occurs. Because the cells are empty **BUT** inside the excel file is a `wordwrap/text wrapping` activated for each row in the column

No idea how to give you a good example of data, becaus as I said it's just a blank cell. And inside the excel file is `wordwrap/text wrapping` activated.

I can take it out manually, but I hvae to work with more than 50 different files and it would be way easier to get rid of this wrapping with a line of code.

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then update you post

Comment: Wild guess because you really do not show enough: you should first coerce the column to `str`: `df['col'].astype(str).str. ...`

Comment: Can you please provide a working sample/code for us to use and debug? The way it is right now, it is too vague to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some non strings values, possible solution is convert column to strings:

```
change_copy.NAMECHANGE = change_copy.NAMECHANGE.astype(str).str.replace("_Ja","_Nein")
```